# Assign a value to a [(ngModel)] input

Tags: node.js, angular

new to MEAN stack here,

I'm trying to insert datas into MongoDB, but with the _id of the connected user, so I have a function which display it :

```
  getSessionInfos(){
    return sessionStorage.getItem('id'); 
  }
```

```
db.collection('transactions').insertOne({
       date : req.body.date,
       titre: req.body.titre,
       description : req.body.description,
       montant : "-" + req.body.montant,
       id: req.body.id, <-------------
       type: "debit"
```

So I thought to myself, alright, I'm gonna create a hidden input with the ID as a value, it's gonna be easier :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.id" value="getSessionInfos()">
```

Except that NO, it seems that you can't change the value of a NGmodel input,
So how am I supposed to do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: any = {
  date: "",
  titre: "",
  description: "",
  montant: "",
  id: sessionStorage.getItem('id'),
  type: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input [hidden]='true' type="text" [(ngModel)]="data?.id" >
```

Comment: ook, but where is the function in this ? 

Comment: You could change your data value from your typescript class then your html will be infected with the new value.

Comment: Oh yes, in the data array ! montant: hh, id: sessionStorage.getItem('id'), (... ) 
It works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngfor="let dataa in data"><input [hidden]='true' type="text" [(ngModel)]="dataa.id" (change)="getSessionInfos()"></ng-container>
```